# How to get Subversion 1.7 support in Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: svn, svnkit

In fact there are 3 sub-questions:

- Is the SVNKit 1.7 snapshot stable enough for basic (update/commit) production usage?
- Is it possible to manually upgrade SnvKit to 1.7 without recompiling different plugins?
- Is there any 1.7-compatible alternative that integrates with Eclipse or PyCharm?

I am interested in getting Subversion 1.7 support in Eclipse or PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: FWIW I updated subclipse shortly after 1.7 came out and I've had no problems with it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've seen significant performance problems with the current version of SVNKit and Subversion 1.7, and because of those problems we've decided to postpone the inclusion of Subversion 1.7 support in IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm. Right now it's planned for inclusion into IntelliJ IDEA 11.1/PyCharm 2.1.

The source code of the Subversion plugin updated for SVN 1.7 compatibility is available in the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition source repository. You can compile the plugin yourself and replace the plugin from IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm with your version.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared my question as to how come svn 1.7 was not in intelliJ...  was starting to doubt the speed of adoption of new technologies!   :)     Keep it up, the best IDE ever! 

That said, I how svn 1.7 official support comes soon..